# create a cluster in EKS in a unsupported version

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I want to create a cluster under EKS in a version that got recently deprecated `1.15` to test something version specific.

my below command is failing

```
 eksctl create cluster --name playgroundkubernetes --region us-east-1 --version 1.15 --nodegroup-name standard-workers --node-type t2.medium --managed
```

is there a workaround where i can create a cluster in version `1.15`.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to create a brand new EKS cluster with a deprecated version. The only option would be to deploy your own cluster (DIY) with something like KOPS or the like.

Comment: thanks @mreferre, will the cluster i create with `KOPS` be listed under EKS cluster? or where will I be able to see the cluster information under AWS Console?

Comment: No, from an AWS perspective that would be a black box. All AWS would know in that case is that there are a bunch of EC2 instances you are using for "something" but there will not be any knowledge by AWS that that is a Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mreferre's comment, if you're trying to just create a Kubernetes cluster and don't need it to be in AWS, you could use Kind (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/quick-start/) or similar to create something much more quickly and probably more cheaply.

Comment: hi lain, i need it to be under `AWS`